# Source code for Android programs and applications

Tags: file-management

How do I view the libraries, directories, source files, etc... for Android programs and apps. Obviously file viewer doesn't show nearly what I am looking for. 8ts all open source, so why can't I access them?

Comment: no, it's not open source. you can find source code for open source apps only https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-Droid

Answer (score 1):

Open source does not mean that the source is included in the Android app. An APK files never contains the code in compiled form. Some time sit means that the source code can be downloaded somewhere on the net.

Usually nowadays you can find the source code of an open source on on one of the three most popular platforms:

- https://Github.com
- https://gitlab.com
- https://sourceforge.net

Typically the project page is linked on the [Google Play] store web page of the app.